# QGIS not importing .map files correctly

Tags: qgis

I use a programe that generates OziExplorer **.map** files along with associated **.jpg** files, in order to break up a large ROI of flown imagery into tiled downloads.

usually I just select all the .map files and drag into QGIS, and it works perfectly.

But now when I do that, i get the following:

[image]

It seems to be completely confused about the order in which the tiles should sit? changing the CRS from EPSG:3395 to something like UTM 30 does not seem to help.

Any reason why QGIS 3.12 should be doing this?

When I test in QGIS 2.18 it works perfectly:

[image]

Comment: Probably something to do with axis order, following switch to proj 6 in latest QGIS.  Probably worth bouncing something to the QGIS issues tracker ~ https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues

Comment: ok thanks, issue raised: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/35600